# Learn Python the Hard Way Ex.41 Confused About For loop

Tags: python-2.7

I am having trouble understanding how one of the for loops works in Learn Python the Hard Way ex.41. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex41.html Below is the code from the lesson.

The loop that I am confused about is `for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):`
Is it iterating over a range of 0 to snippet (of which there are 6 snippet), and adding the extra value of the count of "@@@"? So for the next line of code `param_count = random.randint(1,3)` the extra value of "@@@" is applied?  Or am I way off!?

Cheers
Darren

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
       "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
      "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
      "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
      "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
      "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
    "***.*** = '***'":
      "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

# do they want to drill phrases first
PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True

# load up the words from the website
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
                   random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

        # fake class names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

        # fake other names
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

        # fake parameter lists
        for word in param_names:
           result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results


# keep going until they hit CTRL-D
try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print question

            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER:  %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`snippet.count("@@@")` returns the number of times `"@@@"` appears in `snippet`.

If `"@@@"` appears 6 times, then the for-loop iterates from 0 to 6.

Comment: Thanks @Omar Abdeldayem, hopefully you can help me clarify a little further. So let's say that `"@@@"` appears 3 times. On the first iteration, lets say I get the random integer `2` from the next line of code `param_count = random.randint(1,3)`. Then for the next line of code `param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))' lets say that the random WORDS are 'apple' and 'cheese'. Will the first appended item to `param_names = []` list be `[', apple, cheese']`? Following that, 3 more iterations will be appended to the list? Utlimately, not sure how this works in the whole code

Comment: please note that I didn't end one section of code properly in the previous comment. I did not put a back tick at the end of `param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))` - I mistakenly put a single qoute by mistake, not ending the code section properly

Comment: Yeah, everything you said seems to be correct. Once the `param_names[]` list is built up, all the `"@@@"` instances in `snippet` are replaced with names from `param_names[]`. Let me know if you need more help understanding the code.

Comment: Thanks @Omar Abdeldayem. I played around with the code a little, and know I understand a little better why I was confused. For the function of the total script, it did make sense that there would be more than 1 element passed to the list `param_names = []`. However, there is never more than 1 element passed at any given time, because the count of `@@@` never actually exceeds 1 for any key or value in the dictionary. So the iteration of `for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):` is actually only 1 iteration.

Comment: ..couple this with the fact that I am a newbie and that I was still getting my head around that the looping in the `convert()` class is actually dependent on the looping of the for loop with in the `try` statement towards the bottom of the script took me some studying to get my head around. This is my first introduction to classes, but I think it is actually starting to sink in now! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

"try except" block runs the program until the user hits ^ D.

"While True" loop inside "try" stores list of keys from PHRASES dictonary into snippets. The order of keys is different each time (because of shuffle method). "for loop" inside that "While loop" is to go through each snippet and call convert method on key and value of that snippet.

All "convert method" does it to replace %%%, ***, and @@@ of that key and value with a random word from the url list of words and return a list (results) consists of two strings: one made from the key and one made from the value.

Then the program prints one of the strings as a question, then gets user input (using raw_input("> ")), but no matter what the user entered, it prints the other returned string as the answer.

Inside convert method, we have three different lists : class_names, other_names, and param_names. 
To make class_names, the program counts the number of %%% isnide that key (or value, but they are the same numbers of %%% in them anyways). class_names will be a random list of words in the size of the count of %%%.

other_names is a random list of words again. How many words? in the number of  ***  found in key (or value, does not matter which one because it is the same in any pairs of them)

param_names is a list of strings in the size of the number of @@@ found. Each string consists of one, two or three different words seperated by ,.

'result' is a string. The program goes over the three lists (class_names, param_names and other_names), and replace something in result string with what it already made ready for it. Then append this into results list. The (for sentence in snippet, phrase:) loop runs two times because 'snippet' and 'phrase' are two different strings. So, 'result' string is being made two times (one for question one for answer).

I put one part of this program to a smaller sub program to clarify how a list of a certain size from random words in the url is created:

https://github.com/MahshidZ/python-recepies/blob/master/random_word_set.py

Finally, I suggest to put print statements any where in code that you need to understand better. An an example, for this code I printed a number of variables to get exactly what is going on. This is a good way of debugging without a debugger: (look for the boolean variable DEBUG in my code)

```
DEBUG = 1
if DEBUG:
  print "snippet: " , snippet
  print "phrase: ", phrase
  print "class names: ", class_names
  print "other names: " , other_names
  print "param names: ", param_names
```