# How to read the code of exercise 41 from learn python the hard way?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand the following code and am having a difficult time of it. Can someone help me to understand by answering a couple of questions?

I know that PHRASES (a variable) contains a dictionary, so "class %%%(%%%)" maps to "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%."

Are the lines (line 2-13) also actually create classes or are they just like "strings"? Because it looks like it might be creating classes, but I'm not sure.

I also know that %%%, ***, and @@@ will actually get replaced by actual words somewhere in the code, but don't know how or where because it just all looks so confusing.

So, can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
1 PHRASES = {
2 "class %%%(%%%):":
3  "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
4 "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
5  "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
6 "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
7  "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
8 "*** = %%%()":
9  "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
10 "***.***(@@@)":
11 "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
12 "***.*** = '***'":
13  "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
14 }
```

Oh, and here's the entire code in case you need it:

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
     "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
     "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
     "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
     "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
     "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
    "***.*** = '***'":
     "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

PHRASE_FIRST = False
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True

for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())


def convert(snippet, phrase):
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in
               random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    results = []
    param_names = []

    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        result = sentence[:]

        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        results.append(result)

    return results


try:
    while True:
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print question

            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER:  %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
```

Comment: Could you start here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544008/learn-python-the-hard-way-ex-41-confused-about-for-loop?rq=1

Comment: @ Alfe, because the course purports to be the easier way in the end. @ KevinDTimm, thanks I'll look at it again.

Comment: Look at my explanation in another related question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544008/learn-python-the-hard-way-ex-41-confused-about-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines are creating a dictionary of strings with keys that have similar syntax to a valid Python class definition and values that describe what they are doing.

For example, `"class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)"`

Becomes

```
class %%%(object):
    def __init__(self, ***)
```

> I also know that `%%%`, `***`, and `@@@` will actually get replaced by actual words somewhere in the code, but don't know how or where because it just all looks so confusing.

This bit is pretty obvious, e.g.:

```
result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)
```

The words are fetched from `WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"`.

Comment: 1. So, it's not actually creating a class, correct? It's just a string.

Comment: Thanks! That's what had me confused; I was simply over thinking it. I get it now! Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what the script does is:

1. import modules (random, urllib and sys)
2. define some variable + create a list
3. create a dictionary. Here the classes and the *** or %%% symbols appear, but as strings, nothing magic.
4. A set of functions and loops are defined to change the output flow.

If you call the script (say from the command line, `python oop_test.py`) you are prompted with the questions in abstract way and then the answers are in english.

If however you call the script by defining the argv to english `python oop_test.py english` then you get the questions in english and the ansswer has to be in abstract way.

The block of functions gives the logic to the flow. The final block try/except calls the functions and the dictionary + the random module to randomize the words imported from the url.