# LPYTHW exercise 41: typed everything as it is but it doesn't run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I typed everything as it is, but it just doesn't do anything. The console just goes blank. Does anyone have a clue what is wrong?
I tried to do everything and scanned through the code several times, it looks like it should be exactly as the code that was given...
I don't know why this doesn't run, I will figure it out in time.

```
import random
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"

WORDS = []

PHRASES = {
"class %%%(%%%):":
    "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%",
 "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
    "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** params.",
"class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
    "class %%% has-a function *** that takes self and @@@ params.",
 "*** = %%%()":
    "Set *** to an instance of class %%%",
"***.***(@@@)":
    "From *** get the *** function, call it with params self, @@@.",
"***.*** = '***'":
    "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."}

if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
  PHRASE_FIRST = True
else:
  PHRASE_FIRST = False

for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
  WORDS.append(str(word.strip(), encoding = "utf-8"))

def convert(snippet, phrase):
  class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
  other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
  results = []
  param_names = []

  for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
      param_count = random.randint(1,3)
      param_names.append(' ,'.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

  for sentence in snippet, phrase:
      result = sentence[:]
      #fake class names
      for word in class_names:
          result = result.replace('%%%', word, 1)
      #fake other names
      for word in other_names:
          result = result.replace('***', word, 1)
      #fake param name
      for word in param_names:
          result = result.replace('@@@', word, 1)

      results.append(result)

  return results

try:
  while True:
      snippets = list(PHRASES.keys())
      random.shuffle(snippets)

  for snippet in snippets:
      phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
      question, answer =  convert(snippet, phrase)
      if PHRASE_FIRST:
          question, answer = answer, question

      print(question)
      input("> ")
      print(f"ANSWER: {answer}\n\n")
except EOFError:
  print("\nBye")
```

Comment: I don't know what the correct code should look like, but you have an endless `while True:` loop that shuffles your snippets for eternity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I typed everything as it is

No, you didn't. If you compare it to e. g. the code in the question [How to read the code of exercise 41 from learn python the hard way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568509/how-to-read-the-code-of-exercise-41-from-learn-python-the-hard-way), you can see what Aran-Fey commented - the indentation in the `while True:` loop is wrong.

Comment: thank you so much! struggled with it for hours wondering what was wrong!